# C++ doubly linked list printing in reverse - but I don't want it to

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm creating an STL like container for a doubly linked list. I need it to act like a multiset, where it only contains a single instance of each object, but keeps a count so multiples can be added but only one is actually "stored".

The problem I'm currently having is that when iterating over the an instance of the object I'm getting its elements in reverse order?

I've been pulling my hair on this and can't seem to figure out what's going on... Everything else (so far) is working as expected. It's just the whole reverse thing I can't seem to figure out the cause...

Comment: Try simplifying your code (remove all the "unnecessary" bits - such as searching for elements, removing elements, etc - those are not relevant to your question, so shouldn't be part of the question - you may find that you locate the problem in the process, but even if you don't, it will help you get better help).

Comment: @Mats Petersson, thanks for the suggestion. Cleaned things up, also add example of test code.

Comment: Get rid of the `static unsigned int count = 1;` parts. They're not thread-safe, act as hidden globals, and the "count" of where you are in a repeated element is something that should be part of the iterator, i.e. the iterator should know "I am in the 5th instance of 'a'."

Comment: There are two obvious error sources for your observation: The `iterator` class and the `insert` method.  Use a debugger to see what your code is doing: if the nodes are linked correctly and your iterators work.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone, how would I do this? I'm still new to C++ and trying to wrap my head around iterators is hard enough. I don't understand how I would go about getting the iterator to understand it's the n'th instance of datum??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is in `insert`:

```
    node *curr;
    curr = head->next; //point to first node since we're using dummy head node
    while (curr != tail && c(datum, curr->datum))
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
```

The `while` condition should be `curr != tail && c(curr->datum, datum)`.

This is because the insertion sort should think "while the current item is less than [before] the one I want to insert, skip to the next." Key: current, less than, inserted. `std::less::operator()(a,b)` just does `a < b`. Since you want `curr->datum < datum`, it should be `c(curr->datum, datum)`.

---

Okay, that took longer than expected, because your code:

```
cout << "ml Should be aceelppsu: ";
```

is wrong and should be:

```
cout << "ml Should be aaceelppsu: ";
```

because there are two `'a'`s in `"applesauce"`.

How to solve the iterator problem: First realize that the iterator needs to remember which one of a duplicated item it is currently on. This means it needs to be a member of the iterator:

```
class iterator
{
private:
    node *p;
    unsigned int count;
    friend class MutliLink;
    // NOT a copy ctor -- an initialize-from-ptr ctor.
    iterator(node *ptr) : p(ptr), count(0) { }
    // -- A copy ctor would be iterator(const iterator& iter);
```

Second, I deleted the `iterator` default constructor, since there is no need to have iterators that point at nothing. They might make sense as an `end` iterator in some containers, but in this case `end` is an iterator that points at the dummy `tail` so a null-pointing iterator is not needed.

This means that the only public constructor is the default copy constructor that C++ automagically creates for you. Therefore new iterators can only be constructed from other iterators, and the only thing that can spontaneously create an iterator is `MultiLink`. This should catch some common user mistakes.

Next, we need to fix the increment and decrement (NOTE: no `i` in "decrement") operators. This needs to take `count` into account, and more importantly, the increment and decrement operators need to be compatible with each other, so:

```
iterator i = ml.begin(), j(i);
assert(--++i == j);
```

works. This means we need to explain the *meaning* of `count`. In this case, I define that meaning to be "`count` is the index of the current element, starting at 0, and thus shall not be greater than `p->datumCount` at any time." This changes your preincrement operator into:

```
    iterator &operator++()      // preincrement
    {
        assert(p);
        if (count + 1 < p->datumCount)
        {
            // increment count and return *this
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            // reset count and return next element
            count = 0;
            p = p->next;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

This can be more concisely expressed as:

```
    iterator &operator++()      // preincrement
    {
        assert(p);
        if (++count >= p->datumCount)
        {
            // reset count and return next element
            count = 0;
            p = p->next;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

The preincrement operator is similarly changed:

```
    iterator &operator--()      // predecrement
    {
        assert(p);
        if (count-- == 0)
        {
            // reset count and return previous element
            p = p->prev;
            count = p->datumCount - 1;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

The post- operators don't need changing since they just call the pre- versions.

Comment: this seems to have solved the reverse issue! Thank you! I would love to know how to fix the iterator now as you have mentioned the method I'm using isn't thread safe...

Comment: Updated with the iterator explanation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. This helps more than anything. I really appreciate you taking the time to detail your explanations. Accepting this as the answer.